# Propagating base class errors in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa

I wanted `NSTextField` which will replace empty string with 0 (or minimum allowed value), so I have created custom `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
class NonEmptyNumberFormatter: NSNumberFormatter {    
    override func getObjectValue(obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>, forString string: String, range rangep: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSRange>) throws {
        if string.isEmpty {
            obj.memory = self.minimum ?? 0
        } else {
            try super.getObjectValue(obj, forString: string, range: rangep)
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine for empty strings, however if I set `minimum` property, then entering a value smaller than `minimum` crashes the application.

Is something wrong with `try super.getObjectValue(...)` call?

I want to preserve the base class (`NSNumberFormatter`) behavior for non-empty strings.

Here's a sample gist to test it in the playground: https://gist.github.com/iskeld/a6ba57b145f2f9208fa63efc69d2c517
- I don't understand why `OverridenFormatter` causes error when it's only delegating the call to the base class.

Comment: I'd recommend implementing this via the `NSTextField` delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` (or others), instead of using a formatter.

Comment: @jtbandes `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, sub code=0x0)`

Comment: Not enough information. Which line? Is there an error logged in the console? Or can you see the stack trace in the debugger?

Comment: @jtbandes the console just says `fatal error: `, debugger stops in the `AppDelegate` class header. Sorry, I'm new to Swift/Cocoa and don't know how to debug it further.

Comment: @jtbandes I've included a sample gist which can be executed in the playground and clearly shows what's wrong. I assumed, that if I'm overriding a function and all I'm doing is calling the base implementation, then the function should behave the same as if it wasn't there.  I guess its related to Swift <-> Obj-C bridge.